# React/Node - How can I locate where "Warning: the function is client-side only, does not work on server side" are?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, debugging, isomorphic-javascript

I have a expressjs and react app i'd like to take steps into making isomorphic in baby steps. Im also trying to do this in baby steps but am having a hard time locating where logs like

> "Warning: the function is client-side only, does not work on server side"

from a terminal log as any log provided above or below this warning are unrelated (and obviously this would not come from on the client side).

How can I get some form of stack trace to identify these? Are there any libraries I can install that would help.

Thinking to wire up to `node --inspect` what more insight i can get but sure I'm not the first one to try to solve this and others have a more elegant way of doing so.

Answer (score 0):

This warning occurs when calling subscribe-ui-events' `subscribe` method server-side.

https://github.com/yahoo/subscribe-ui-event/blob/f197c22ddb10c6b0bf09453acc274d46d47ad0b7/index.js#L14